# How to auto-refresh page title every X seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbulletin

Our forum has a notification system that appends (#) to the page title, # being the number of current notifications they have (messages, likes, etc). This is not done by AJAX or anything - just a call to # of notifications using their template system for several pages, like so:

```
<title>({vb:raw total_notices}) - Our Site Title</title>
```

I want to make the title auto-refresh every 10 seconds or so to reflect the latest updates. I have tried this in our footer template (loads for every page) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
        document.title = document.title;
        }, 3000);
 </script>
```

But it does not actually refresh, just grabs the existing title. I know the code itself is working/refreshing because if I change it to

```
document.title = "Test";
```

It updates the title to "Test" no problem.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you updating it without ajax?

Comment: Why not just refresh the page?

Comment: @enginefree, that would add a lot of load to the server. We just want the title to refresh - people will be working with the page in the mean time.

Comment: @Wiz, we just put our "Total Notifications" variable into the title (the vb:raw thing is vBulletin's way of calling a DB variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal because doing`document.title = document.title;` doesn't do a request to your forum server.
If you would like to refresh your title you must do a request.

If you have jquery on your page you can do that:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get(document.location.toString()).then(function (data){
       //find and set the title of the page
       document.title = data.match(/<title>(.+)<\/title>/)[1];
    });
}, 3000);
```

That work but it isn't a good idea because this code to a lot of requests on your server...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I will turn down the requests so it doesn't do too much :)